# Streaming live webcam Feed over a network using Gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer

i want to make a **video chat app**. i know how to detect **webcam via gstreamer** but have no clue as in how to transfer that feed onto network in real time.
 i am using python as programing language.

Comment: ok since no one was replying here so i dug a little and found this 
http://www.olpcnews.com/forum/index.php?topic=1752.5;wap2

Comment: yup, something like that. Also see: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-tcpserversink.html